# Using a value of an attribute inside another attribute in a tag

Tags: html, reactjs, jsx

this could be very dumb to ask but I am new to javascript. I am following a react tutorial, and I wonder if I can use the value (70) in  text in CircularProgressbar  tag. I don't know how to search this, so if you know and help me get through this I would appreciate it.
I know I dont need to do like this, or I know there's another option, just curiosity.
Thank you.

```
const Featured = () => {
  return (
    <div className="featured">
      <div className="top">
        <h1 className="title">Total Revenue</h1>
        <MoreVertIcon fontSize="small" />
      </div>
      <div className="bottom">
        <div className="featuredChart">
            <CircularProgressbar value={70} **text={Featured.CircularProgressbar.value}**/>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: One solution is to make it a variable / state and use it twice in text and in value. you also could use refs but that's too much x)

Comment: What is `<CircularProgressBar>`? Is it a component you wrote yourself, or from a third party library? How do you what it to be shown?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like what you want is that to be state. I believe that value is not always going to be 70?. You would also have to handle the change of that progress bar so that you get that value changing

```js
const Featured = () => {
  const [ progress, setProgress ] = useState(0)
  const handleProgressChange = (newProgress) => {
    setProgress(newProgress)
  }
  return (
    <div className="featured">
      <div className="top">
        <h1 className="title">Total Revenue</h1>
        <MoreVertIcon fontSize="small" />
      </div>
      <div className="bottom">
        <div className="featuredChart">
            <CircularProgressbar value={progress} text={progress} onChange={handleProgressChange}/>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Note I don't know what props exactly your `CircularProgressbar` component offers (i'm guessing `onChange` here but might be called different). But chances are that there some sort of change handler prop available for you to be able to *control* the component with your own value.

Read some more about controlled uncontrolled components [here](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/sharing-state-between-components#)